# SOAPUI free: how to composite/pretty print REST projects

Tags: wsdl, soapui, pretty-print

I have REST project, which I want to commit to repo, with the goal of possible contributions from some team members.
But there can be troubles during resolving conflicts, because of one huge XML project file.

2 known recipes:

- Use Pro version of SoapUI, and set "Composite Proj" parameter to True. In result project will decomposited, and(lesser) troubles with merging
- Set True to property WSDL>PrettyPrintProjects

But how to pretty print/composite REST projects in SOAPUI Free? That WSDL property does not impact on saving such projs.

Cheers.